# Does IIS Garbage Collect hosted Service applications when idle?

Tags: iis, garbage-collection, iis-7.5, wcf-data-services

All,

I have developed a WCF ODATA Services application and hosted it in IIS7. The service application has an in-memory cache which loses all its cached value if the client is idle for about 15 mins or so.

While troubleshooting, i figured out that the application logic is proper and doesn't do a bulk removal of objects from the cache.

So, I am puzzled if IIS does clears the service objects when there are no client connected to it for quite sometime.?

Is this GC behavior true? If so, how do i control it?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default the IIS7 Application Pools have a 20 minute Idle Timeout value set after which the application pool is unloaded from memory along with all your cached data.

You can [increase the Idle Timeout](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771956%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) or even set it to '0' which causes it to never timeout by selecting the application pool hosting your site in IIS Manager, choosing 'Advanced Properties' in the Actions pane and then setting the value of 'Idle Time-out (minutes) value' to the new timeout you want and clicking ok. (There are a couple of screen shots of this on Brad Kinsley's blog posting ['IIS7 Application Pool Idle Time-out Settings'](http://brad.kingsleyblog.com/IIS7-Application-Pool-Idle-Time-out-Settings/)

One option to consider is setting up an out-of-proc cache so that even if IIS does recycle your app, the memory cache persists or setup a backing store for your existing cache so that if the app pool recycles the cache re-populates from the backing store.

The Enterprise Library's Caching Application block is one example of a caching solution with such a backing store. See ['Caching Application Block and database backing store'](http://itworksonmymachine.wordpress.com/2009/02/06/caching-application-block-and-database-backing-store/) for more information on that.